# 2 limits with riemann sum/integral

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

So i have problems calculating 2 limits :

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln(2!)-\ln(n!)-n(\ln(n)))}{n} $$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\sqrt{n^2-k^2}}{n^2}$$

So i have the basic idea that i will somehow need to use partitions.
I know at least to get $$\frac{1}{n}$$ out of fraction, however that's where i get stuck.
So i know i need to get a set of partitions, then add one element on edge. possibly 0 or 1, and define a map, and then use definite integral with $$[a,b]$$
So basically i need to use Riemann sum to calculate limits.
Any hint or even help with one limit would be really appreciated.
Thank you in advance. And if there is any similar questions already(possibly duplicates), i'm apologizing for that also. But i did not find any.

Comment: The second limit is easy. Divide the numerator and denominator by $n$, you get$\sum \frac{\sqrt{1-(k/n)^2}}{n}$ which is $\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1-(x)^2}.dx$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$1)$ $\log n! = \sum_{k=1}^n \log k = \sum_{k=1}^n \log(k/n) - n\log n$

$2)$ $$ \frac{\sqrt{n^2 - k^2}}{n^2}  = \frac1{n}\sqrt{\frac{n^2 - k^2}{n^2}} = \frac1{n} \sqrt{1 - (\frac{k}{n})^2}$$

$3)$ $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac1{n} \sum_{k=1}^n f(k/n) = \int_0^1 f(x) dx$$

Comment: So as $$f(x)$$ i can use: $$\sqrt{1-x^2}$$?

Comment: Yes ${{{{{}}}}}$

Comment: Also D={1/n,....n/n} and C={0,....,n/n} we use D and C as notation first is partitions and second is used as the second set in Riemann sum. If you understand. Also i would appreciate if you could post more detailed  for first limit. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you said @user246608. Anyway, I think that you can work out the first limit by yourself given my hint. Just write it down on a paper.

Answer (score 0):

All set up now:
$$\frac{\sqrt{n^2-k^2}}{n^2} = \frac{\sqrt{n^2(1-(\frac{k}{n})^2)}}{n^2} = \frac{\sqrt{1-(\frac{k}{n})^2}}{n} $$