# Find the limit of $\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty }{ \sum _{ k=1 }^{ n }{ \frac { \sqrt { { n }^{ 2 } - { k }^{ 2 } } } { { n }^{ 2 } } } } $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Need help to find the limit of $$\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \sum _{ k=1 }^{ n }{ \frac { \sqrt { { n }^{ 2 } - { k }^{ 2 } }  } { { n }^{ 2 } }  }  }$$

Comment: Hint: Riemann sum.

Comment: It's frowned upon to ask a question on this site without having shown your attempt at the problem. Update your post to include what you have tried.

Comment: Sry, new to the forum. Still have some difficulties with formula syntax.

Comment: read this https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Sm1 No worries - the reluctance of users to answer questions with little effort shown is mostly to stop people using the site to do their homework for them. Just try to make sure when you ask a question to show what you've tried. Here's a guide for formatting equations https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thank you for a helpful links

Comment: Possible duplicate of [2 limits with riemann sum/integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1558325/2-limits-with-riemann-sum-integral)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \sum _{ k=1 }^{ n }{ \frac { \sqrt { { n }^{ 2 } - { k }^{ 2 } }  } { { n }^{ 2 } }  }  }=\lim_{n \to \infty } \sum _{ k=1 }^{ n }\frac{1}{n}\sqrt{1-\frac{k^2}{n^2}}$$

Replace $\frac{1}{n}$ with ${dx}$ and $\frac{k}{n}$ with $x$

$$ \lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }\sum _{ k=1 }^{ n }\frac{1}{n}\sqrt{1-\frac{k^2}{n^2}}=\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x^2}{dx}$$

I obtained the bounds 0 and 1 using

$$\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_k^n\frac{b-a}nf\left(k\frac{b-a}{n}\right)$$

Comment: I'd like to note that you can justify this with $\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_k^n\frac{b-a}nf\left(k\frac{b-a}{n}\right)$ (hence where the bounds $0$ and $1$ come from)

Comment: Yes that's what I did. dodo you want me to include this in the answer?

Comment: You could do - the reason I pointed it out is that the bounds seem to come out of nowhere

Comment: But one could also found the bounds  like this $\frac{k}{n}$ is replaced by x but k can go max up to n thus x can go up to 1  also k is minimum 1 thus minimum x is 1/n but   $n \to \infty$ thus minimum  x is 0

Answer (score 1):

As noticed by Riemann sum we obtain

$$\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }\sum _{ k=1 }^{ n }\frac{1}{n}\sqrt{1-\frac{k^2}{n^2}}=\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x^2}{dx}=\frac{\pi}4$$

As an alternative, just to explore other ways, since for a fixed $k$ by binomial series we have

$$\sqrt{1-\frac{k^2}{n^2}}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \binom{\frac12}{j}\left(-\frac{k^{2}}{n^{2}}\right)^j $$

and therefore by [**Faulhaber's formula**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula)

$$\sum _{ k=1 }^{ n }\frac{1}{n}\sqrt{1-\frac{k^2}{n^2}}
=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \left[\binom{\frac12}{j}\frac{(-1)^j}{n^{2j+1}}\sum_{k=1}^n k^{2j}\right]
\to\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^j\binom{\frac12}{j}}{{2j+1}}$$

and since for the [binomial coefficient with $n=1/2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Binomial_coefficient_with_n_=_%C2%BD) we have

$${{\frac12}\choose{j}}={{2j}\choose{j}}\frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{2^{2j}(2j-1)}\implies \binom{\frac12}{j}\frac{(-1)^j}{{2j+1}}=\frac{\binom{2j}{j}}{2^{2j}(1-4j^2)}$$

we obtain that

> $$\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^j\binom{\frac12}{j}}{{2j+1}}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{\binom{2j}{j}}{2^{2j}(1-4j^2)}=\frac{\pi}4$$

Comment: How do you justify that last equality to $\pi/4$?

Comment: @Jam I have not anyidea about that! I'm assuming it is true from the result obtained by Riemann sum. I just wanted explore this other ways. Numerical extimation confirm the result. Do you have any idea how to derive the result in a different way without using Riemann sum?

Comment: If you format your links as `[link name](link address)`, you can fit the whole URL in the link - otherwise I can't click on it.

Comment: And I'm not sure about how to prove the equality to $\pi/4$. I'd got as far as you but haven't thought of how to do the last step.

Comment: @Jam [sum 1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+binom(1%2F2,j)((-1)%5Ej%2F(1%2B2j)))

Comment: @Jam I can't link the second sum, I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: No worries. I'm not sure I'd be able to help anyway haha. But for the record, you could try putting the link through bit.ly and then using that as the link for a comment.

Comment: @Jam Good idea! [sum 2](https://bit.ly/2MKHltv)

Comment: @Jam I might create an OP to ask a question about that!